# Receiving Data from ِAndroid JSON to PHP

Tags: php, android, database, json, android-asynctask

My App sends username and password to PHP file using JSON then PHP File Reads the user Columns and status from Database MY Problem is that i added everything that reads JSON from Android App in the PHP File but No data returned to that user please tell me what's wrong with my code

Application JSON Activity Code

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
             private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(fishtank.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            //Temp
                SharedPreferences settings =  getSharedPreferences("mySettings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 us = settings.getString("storedWifiUser", "");
                    ps = settings.getString("storedWifiPass", "");
                 try {
                     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
                     json.put("user", us); 
                     json.put("pass", ps);

                     postData(json);


                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();}  //Temp
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();   
                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                return json;
            }
            //Temp
            public void postData(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                try { 
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                    List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);    
                    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json.toString()));
                    //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");  
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

                    if(response != null) {
                        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        //input stream is response that can be shown back on android
                    }

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
            //Temp
             @Override

             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 try {

                     System.out.println("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());
                     JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject("status");
                     String tog1="";
                     String tog2="";
                     String tog3="";
                     if(c.has("fil"))

                            tog1 = c.getString("fil");

                        if(c.has("HEA"))
                         tog2 = c.getString("HEA");

                        if(c.has("LED"))
                            tog3 = c.getString("LED");


                                        if(tog1.equals("ON"))
                                        {   toggle1.setChecked(true);}
                                        else{ toggle1.setChecked(false);}
                                             if(tog2.equals("ON"))
                                             {   toggle2.setChecked(true);}
                                             else{   toggle2.setChecked(false);}
                                             if(tog3.equals("ON"))
                                             {    toggle3.setChecked(true);}
                                             else{toggle3.setChecked(false);}

                             } catch (JSONException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }

             }






        }//End Json
```

PHP File Code

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","pet_home");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
if(isset($_POST['json'])){
    $json=$_POST['json'];
    $data2=json_decode($json,TRUE);
    $u=$data2->{'user'};
    $p=$data2->{'pass'};
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND password='$p'");
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

         if($row_cnt>0){     
             $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
            $data = array('success'=>true, 'status'=>array("fil" => $row['filter_st'], "HEA"=> $row['heat_st'], "LED" =>$row['led_st'])); 
         }else{
            $data = array('success'=>false);
         }

       echo json_encode($data);
 }



mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Logcat

```
12-12 20:22:14.291: W/EGL_genymotion(2044): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-12 20:22:14.319: W/EGL_genymotion(2044): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-12 20:22:14.607: I/JSON Response :(2044): {"error":"No POST value from Android App","success":false}
12-12 20:22:14.607: W/System.err(2044): org.json.JSONException: No value for status
12-12 20:22:14.611: W/System.err(2044):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
12-12 20:22:14.611: W/System.err(2044):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:573)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at com.set.petshome.fishtank$JSONParse.onPostExecute(fishtank.java:326)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at com.set.petshome.fishtank$JSONParse.onPostExecute(fishtank.java:1)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-12 20:22:14.615: W/System.err(2044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 20:22:14.619: W/System.err(2044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-12 20:22:14.619: W/System.err(2044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-12 20:22:14.619: W/System.err(2044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-12 20:22:14.619: W/System.err(2044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this,

```
   if(isset($_POST['json'])){
        $json=$_POST['json'];
        $data2=json_decode($json,TRUE);
        $u=$data2->{'user'};
        $p=$data2->{'pass'};
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND password='$p'");
            $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

             if($row_cnt>0){     
                 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
                $data = array('success'=>true, 'error'=>'',  'status'=>array("fil" => $row['filter_st'], "HEA"=> $row['heat_st'], "LED" =>$row['led_st'])); 
             }else{
                $data = array('success'=>false, 'error' => 'No records found');
             }               

     }else{
         $data = array('success'=>false, 'error' => 'No POST value from Android App');
     }

     echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: May be the reason for `echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();` please run php file in browser and make sure you got the proper json value

Comment: `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: json in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\new\check2.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\new\check2.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\new\check2.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
{"success":false}`

Comment: I have updated my answer, Mean while, $_POST['json'] is not set so that it gives the error as mentioned by you

Comment: Same Crash , is it possible that JSON Code in android have problem ??-Post Updated

Comment: Check php file in browser and makesure you have any error or you getting json properly. Main reason i assumed is from android the json is not posted or mismatching the post variable name.

Comment: after running PHP File in browser nothing displayed

Comment: System.out.println("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());  try using like Log.i("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());

Comment: So without json post value php file wont run now, if you post json only it will supply the output

Comment: I have updated my answer , please use that to know the what output getting from php

Comment: No reponse in the logcat and Crash again post updated 
thanks do you have other possible errors ?

Comment: You can used to log the step by step in receiving json side

Comment: PHP After run {"success":false,"error":"No POST value from Android App")

Comment: Logcat updated response shows No POST value from Android App
But why ?

Comment: Because of there is no post from Android app, please check that